# Python outputs parentheses

Tags: python

I'm sorta new to python, and I wanted to try to create a program that finds the slope of two inputted points. I assume I'm doing fine on the math part, but the output part is my problem. This is my code:

```
import math
x1 = input("x1 = ")
y1 = input("y1 = ")
x2 = input("x2 = ")
y2 = input("y2 = ")
chy = y2 - y1
chx = x2 - x1
slope = 'Slope = ', chy, '/', chx
print (slope)
```

and this is my expected output:

```
x1 = 1
y1 = 1
x2 = 2
y2 = 2
Slope = 1/1
```

and this is my ACTUAL output:

```
x1 = 1
y1 = 1
x2 = 2
y2 = 2
('Slope = ', 1, '/', 1)
```

any help?

Comment: `slope` is a tuple. You want string concatenation instead.

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or Python 2? `print` is a function in Python 3, but it's a statement in Python 2, so the behaviour is different.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, `slope` is a tuple (a sequence of Python objects), which is not what you want.  What you want to do is

```
slope = 'Slope = ' + str(chy) + "/"+ str(chx)
```

This uses string concatenation (every part is a string, it is all put together).

Alternatively, you can use string formatting.

```
slope = "Slope = {}/{}".format(chy,chx)
```

Answer (score 3):

You want string concatenation:

```
slope = 'Slope = ' + str(chy) + '/' + str(chx)
```

The `+` operator is used in Python to concatenate strings. However, it will give an error if you don't convert `chy` and `chx` to strings (by using `str()`), since they currently have numerical values.

Another way to print strings is to use string formatting:

```
slope = 'Slope = {}/{}'.format(str(chy), str(chx))
```

Comment: It's cleaner if you do `slope = 'Slope = {} / {}'.format(str(chy), str(chx))`. Same effect, better code.

Comment: @intelis Not necessarily.

Comment: @intboolstring can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm certainly not a python professional, but I would think of formatting as an alternative.

Comment: @intelis: Well, no need `str()` here. Just `slope = 'Slope = {} / {}'.format(chy, chx)`.

Comment: @intboolstring: Use `format()` to do this is a good idea, because this would be more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to my answer :)